# How to extract an array using json extractor and parse it to remove dupes in Jmeter

Tags: groovy, jmeter, performance-testing, beanshell, json-extract

JSON response is returned in the following format, I need to extract values from the first index of the array for example 925,88 using groovy or perhaps another language, and then store them into a variable to pass them along in the next request. Also, values need to be unique

```
[
    [
        22588,
        [
            925,
            88
        ],
        0,
        0,
        0,
        null,
        "moderate"
   ]
```

Any help would be appreciated!

Thanks

Comment: no way to help without json data sample

Comment: updated the post, lmk if that helps. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

1. Add [JSR223 PostProcessor](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JSR223_PostProcessor) after the JSON Extractor
2. Put the following code into "Script" area:

   ```
   def numbers = []

   1.upto(vars.get('foo_matchNr') as int, { index ->
       new groovy.json.JsonSlurper().parseText(vars.get('foo_' + index)).each { number ->
           numbers.add(number)
       }
   })

   vars.put('payload', new groovy.json.JsonBuilder(numbers.sort().unique()).toPrettyString())
   ```
3. Replace `foo` with the actual [JMeter Variable](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html) name you use in the JSON Extractor
4. Use `${payload}` where you need to send unique numbers

More information:

- [Apache Groovy - Parsing and producing JSON](https://groovy-lang.org/json.html)
- [Apache Groovy - Why and How You Should Use It](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/groovy-new-black)

Comment: never mind, the issue was with the way I was extracting the JSON response, the solution you provided is working now. Thanks a ton! :)